# Carrera de arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, python-3.7

```
import random
```

> Juego: Yo tengo un circuito con 3 jugadores. Los  jugadores que lleguen a la última posición son los ganadores. Reglas: 1 jugador puede avanzar 3 posiciones mientras que el resto solo 1 posición, esto no significa que unicamente un jugador puede avanzar las 3 posiciones, sino que cualquiera de los 3 lo puede hacer al reiniciar el bucle

```
circuito = [["a", "----", "----", "----", "----", "----"], ["b", "----", "----", "----", "----", "----"], ["c", "----", "----", "----", "----", "----"]]
listaNombres = ["a", "b", "c"]
listaGanadores = []
tresPasos = 3
unPaso = 1

while listaGanadores == []:
```

> Me coge un nombre aleatorio, osea mi intencion es que mientras que un jugador avazca 3 pasos, el resto avanzca uno

```
nombreAleatorio = random.randint(0, 2)
```

> Esto lo uso para limpiar mi circuito, llenandolo entero de "----"

```
for i in range(len(circuito)):
    for j in range(len(circuito[i])):
        circuito[i][j] = "----"
```

> Tengo problemas aquí, porque el nombre del participante al cambiarse durante el bucle while,
> estos nombres cogen posiciones que no son correctas

```
for i in range(len(circuito)):
    for j in range(len(circuito[i])):
        if i == nombreAleatorio:                
            circuito[i][tresPasos] = listaNombres[nombreAleatorio]
        else:
            circuito[i][unPaso] = listaNombres[i]

for i in range(len(circuito)):
    print(circuito[i])                
    if circuito[i][5] == listaNombres[i]:
        listaGanadores.append(listaNombres[i])
print()


tresPasos += 3
unPaso += 1

if tresPasos > 5:
    tresPasos = 5
    
if unPaso > 5:
    unPaso = 1
```

print("Ganador/es: ",listaGanadores)

> Quiero algo similar a esto:

```
a ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                       
b ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                       
c ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
                                      

---- a     ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
---- b     ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
---- ----  ---- c    ---- ---- ----                                      
                                      
---- a    ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
---- ---- ---- ----  b   ---- ----                                      
---- ---- ---- ----  c   ---- ----                                      
                                      
---- ---- ---- ---- a    ---- ----                                      
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- b                                         
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- c                                      


a ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                       
b ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                       
c ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
                                      

---- a     ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
---- b     ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
---- ----  ---- c    ---- ---- ----                                      
                                      
---- a    ---- ---- ---- ---- ----                                      
---- ---- ---- ----  b   ---- ----                                      
---- ---- ---- ----  c   ---- ----                                      
                                      
---- ---- ---- ---- a    ---- ----                                      
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- b                                         
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- c                                      

Ganador/es: [a, b]
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de cual es la pregunta. ¿Es que te da incorrecto los ganadores?

Comment: +1 Por una pregunta bien formulada e ilustrada.

Comment: Quiero conseguir que el programa pueda darme uno, dos o tres ganadores, según lo que haga cuando se ejecute. Pero yo solo consigo un ganador, eso porque únicamente un jugador puede dar tresPasos+=3 y cuando llega a la última posición pues ya gana. Quiero conseguir que los jugadores puedan dar 3 pasos cualquiera de ellos, es decir, que no de los tresPasos+=3 el mismo jugador. Así ya podría conseguir uno o varios ganadores, pero no consigo entender la lógica de como hacerlo

Comment: Por favor, publica tu programa en una sola pieza. Tal cual está los corredores no parten desde la primera posición.

Comment: No se entiende el ejemplo final en que muestras un caso de cómo debería ejecutarse. Lo que yo veo en ese ejemplo es que se juegan dos carreras, ambas idénticas, y en ambas ganan (o más bien empatan) b y c. En cambio pones que la salida debería decir "Ganadores: a, b" ¿cómo es eso? Creo que hay algún error

Answer (score 2):

Tuve que reordenar el programa para ir entendiendolo, y al final termine con esto:

```
import random
circuito = [["a", "----", "----", "----", "----", "----"], ["b", "----", "----", "----", "----", "----"], ["c", "----", "----", "----", "----", "----"]]
listaNombres = ["a", "b", "c"]
listaGanadores = []
tresPasos = 3
unPaso = 1
# posiciones me dice en que lugar de la pista está cada corredor
posiciones = [0,0,0]
# meta es el indice de la meta en circuito.
meta = len(circuito[0]) - 1

def limpia_circuito():
    """
    Deja el circuito vacio, sin corredores
    """
    for i in range(len(circuito)):
        for j in range(len(circuito[i])):
            circuito[i][j] = "----"

def print_circuito():
    """
    Imprime el circuito con sus corredores.
    """
    for i in range(len(circuito)):
        print(circuito[i])
    print()


print_circuito()
while listaGanadores == []:
    limpia_circuito()

    nombreAleatorio = random.randint(0, 2)
    for i in range(len(posiciones)):
        #   Calcular la siguiente posición para el corredor.
        posiciones[i] += tresPasos if i == nombreAleatorio else unPaso
        #   Revisar si el corredor llego a la meta.
        if posiciones[i] >= meta:
            #   Corredor llego a la meta, inscribirlo en la lista de ganadores.
            listaGanadores.append(listaNombres[i])
            posiciones[i] = meta
        #   Poner al corredor en su nueva posición
        circuito[i][posiciones[i]] = listaNombres[i]

    print_circuito()


print("Ganador/es: ",listaGanadores)
```

Lo simplifique usando una lista donde llevo las posiciones actualizadas de los corredores.

produce:

Un ganador:

```
['a', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['b', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['c', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']

['----', 'a', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['----', '----', '----', 'b', '----', '----']
['----', 'c', '----', '----', '----', '----']

['----', '----', 'a', '----', '----', '----']
['----', '----', '----', '----', '----', 'b']
['----', '----', 'c', '----', '----', '----']

Ganador/es:  ['b']
```

Dos ganadores

```
['a', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['b', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['c', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']

['----', 'a', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['----', '----', '----', 'b', '----', '----']
['----', 'c', '----', '----', '----', '----']

['----', '----', 'a', '----', '----', '----']
['----', '----', '----', '----', 'b', '----']
['----', '----', '----', '----', 'c', '----']

['----', '----', '----', 'a', '----', '----']
['----', '----', '----', '----', '----', 'b']
['----', '----', '----', '----', '----', 'c']

Ganador/es:  ['b', 'c']
```

Tres ganadores

```
['a', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['b', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['c', '----', '----', '----', '----', '----']

['----', 'a', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['----', 'b', '----', '----', '----', '----']
['----', '----', '----', 'c', '----', '----']

['----', '----', 'a', '----', '----', '----']
['----', '----', '----', '----', 'b', '----']
['----', '----', '----', '----', 'c', '----']

['----', '----', '----', '----', '----', 'a']
['----', '----', '----', '----', '----', 'b']
['----', '----', '----', '----', '----', 'c']

Ganador/es:  ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo entendí correctamente, no necesitas tener un array con el circuito, ya que eso complica bastante la lógica por tener que andar buscando dónde está cada corredor dentro de ese array.

De hecho, precisamente uno de tus fallos es que no mantienes por separado la posición de cada corredor en el array, ya que si por ejemplo el corredor "a" avanzó solo 1 paso en el primer turno, pero le toca avanzar 3 en el siguiente, debería terminar en la "casilla" 4, pero tal como tú lo tienes terminaría en la casilla 6 (pues incrementas la variable `tresPasos` de 3 en 3 y mueves siempre al corredor "elegido" a la posición indicada por esa variable.

Por tanto creo que sería una alternativa más simple el tener un array de tres elementos, llamémosle por ejemplo `posiciones` que indica dónde está cada uno de los corredores. Antes de empezar la carrera el array tendrá  `[0, 0, 0]` indicando que los tres están en la casilla de salida. El elegido incrementará su posición en 3, los restantes la incrementarán en 1, así en cada turno. Al final del turno se comprueba cuáles tienen una posición mayor o igual a 5, y se les mete en la lista de ganadores.

El array "circuito" es innecesario para mantener las posiciones de los corredores. Basta el array `posiciones` con los tres enteros antes explicados.

A la hora de imprimir el estado de la carrera tampoco necesitas el array "circuito" pues se trata simplemente de imprimir una "calle" formada por segmentos de "----" excepto en el lugar que ocupa cada corredor, donde debe salir su nombre. Esta salida puedes generarla a partir de lo que hay en el array `posiciones`, con una función como la siguiente:

```
listaNombres = ["a", "b", "c"]
posiciones = [0,0,0]
longitud_calle = 6

def print_circuito():
    for i in range(len(posiciones)):
      for j in range(longitud_calle):
        if j==posiciones[i]: 
          print("{}   ".format(listaNombres[i]), end=" ")
        else:
          print("----", end=" ")
      if posiciones[i] > j:
        print(listaNombres[i], end = "*")
      print()
```

Fijate en que para cada calle (hay tantas como elementos en `posiciones`) se imprime una calle, que es un bucle con `longitud_calle` repeticiones (6), y en cada iteración de ese bucle se imprime bien "----" si el corredor no está en esa posición, o bien el nombre del corredor (con tres espacios por la derecha para que quede bien alineado).

Me he permitido una modificación y es que si el corredor ya se ha salido de la calle (por ejemplo, corre 3 pasos el primer turno y otros 3 en el segundo, con lo que termina en posición 6) se le imprime también al final de la calle, con un asterisco al lado para indicar que se ha salido.

Una vez tenemos esa función preparada, la carrera sería simplemente así:

```
import random 
listaGanadores = []

while listaGanadores == []:
  print_circuito()              # Imprimir las posiciones antes de elegir uno
  elegido = random.randint(0, 2)    # Elegir uno y mostrarlo para depuración
  print("Elegido", listaNombres[elegido])

  # Hacer que el elegido avance 3 y los demás 1
  for i in range(len(posiciones)):
    if i==elegido:
      posiciones[i]+=3
    else:
      posiciones[i]+=1

    # Verificar si alguien ha ganado en este turno
    if posiciones[i] >= longitud_calle -1:
      listaGanadores.append(listaNombres[i])

# Al terminar la carrera, imprimir otra vez el circuito para ver las posiciones finales
print_circuito()
print("Ganador/es: ",listaGanadores)
```

### Algunos ejemplos de ejecución.

Una en la que gana directamente un corredor (b es elegido dos veces seguidas):

```
a    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
b    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
c    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Elegido b
---- a    ---- ---- ---- ---- 
---- ---- ---- b    ---- ---- 
---- c    ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Elegido b
---- ---- a    ---- ---- ---- 
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- b*
---- ---- c    ---- ---- ---- 
Ganador/es:  ['b']
```

Otra en la que empatan dos (realmente "a" ha llegado más lejos que "c", pues "a" termina en la casilla 6 mientras que "c" lo hace en la 5, pero según las normas del juego entiendo que es un empate ya que ambos llegan a (o cruzan) la meta en el mismo turno.

```
a    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
b    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
c    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Elegido a
---- ---- ---- a    ---- ---- 
---- b    ---- ---- ---- ---- 
---- c    ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Elegido c
---- ---- ---- ---- a    ---- 
---- ---- b    ---- ---- ---- 
---- ---- ---- ---- c    ---- 
Elegido a
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- a*
---- ---- ---- b    ---- ---- 
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- c    
Ganador/es:  ['a', 'c']
```

Y un caso poco frecuente en que empatan los tres:

```
a    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
b    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
c    ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Elegido a
---- ---- ---- a    ---- ---- 
---- b    ---- ---- ---- ---- 
---- c    ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Elegido b
---- ---- ---- ---- a    ---- 
---- ---- ---- ---- b    ---- 
---- ---- c    ---- ---- ---- 
Elegido c
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- a    
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- b    
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- c    
Ganador/es:  ['a', 'b', 'c']
```